# Spring cloud config no lee directorios de Github

Tags: java, spring, github, cloud

Estoy configurando spring cloud config con github para tener repositorios separados de distintos proyectos, pero resulta que no hay forma de que el config me lea el Github de la forma correcta. Solo me lee los ficheros yml que tengo en la raíz. Es el siguiente repo: `https://github.com/SeNTiHaDeS/config--repos`

Como veis, tengo en la raíz un producto yml que contiene el puerto donde quiero que se levante el servicio, y tengo una carpeta producto que contiene el mismo archivo.

La cosa es que si en el config server pongo lo siguiente, me lee el archivo sin problemas, en cambio si lo  que quiero es que coja el archivo que tengo dentro de la carpeta producto, ya no me lo coge.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cambio el git uri por `https://github.com/SeNTiHaDeS/config--repos/tree/main/producto`  o por `https://github.com/SeNTiHaDeS/config--repos/producto`, para tratar de que coja el archivo `producto.yml` que hay dentro de la carpeta producto, pero no hay manera de que el servidor lo detecte, y cuando ejecuto el microservicio producto, en el config server me da el error siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el application.yml del microservicio producto tengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podría poner que me coja también lo que hay dentro de un directorio y no lo de la raiz de github?

Un saludo y gracias de antemano!

PD:Correcto @Benito-B, es tal cuál como dices. La cosa es que lo que yo quería es tener en un mismo repo las configuraciones de los distintos proyectos dividido por carpetas, y cada carpeta tendría el yml de su correspondiente microservicio, como comentas. Por eso quería hacer la separación por carpetas, no sé si me he explicado. Sería posible?

******Solución (gracias a @Benito-B):******
Nueva linea en el application.properties del servidor de configuración que haga referencia a la carpeta del repositorio donde quieres escoger los archivos, de esta forma:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths=nombreCarpeta
```

Comment: Y con la ruta real al archivo ya probaste? `https://github.com/SeNTiHaDeS/config--repos/blob/main/producto/producto.yml`

Comment: Sí, correcto, también probé, y nada. Mismo error

Comment: Normalmente no hace falta especificar la ruta del archivo.... siempre y cuando el nombre del archivo coincida con el nombre de la aplicación, cloud config debería saber darle a la API la configuración correcta. Al menos yo en las pruebas que hice con varios microservicios siempre dejé los archivos de configuración todos en la ruta base, y nunca tuve problemas. No hay necesidad de separarlos por carpetas si en el repo lo único que tienes es archivos de configuración... ya están clasificados por el nombre del servicio al que pertenecen :)

Comment: Correcto @Benito-B, es tal cuál como dices. La cosa es que lo que yo quería es tener en un mismo repo las configuraciones de los distintos proyectos dividido por carpetas, y cada carpeta tendría el yml de su correspondiente microservicio, como comentas. Por eso quería hacer la separación por carpetas, no sé si me he explicado. Sería posible?

Comment: Supuestamente es posible pero tienes que indicarle las rutas en las que buscar los archivos mediante la configuración `spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths: -carpeta1 -carpeta2 -carpeta3...` Cada guión debe ir en una línea nueva, igual que todas las configuraciones multilínea. Aquí lo explican: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/252#issuecomment-441650013. Con esa estructura puedes tener dentro de cada carpeta las diferentes configuraciones para diferentes entornos, y todo sin mezclar los yml

Comment: Perfecto @Benito-B, solucionado. SI no te importa , añado tu solución a mi pregunta. Muchas gracias!!!!!!

Comment: Si me importa. La solución no debería ir en la pregunta, puesto que así no podrás cerrarla! Añádela como respuesta, explica y ejemplifica un poco cómo queda la configuración y la estructura de carpetas (si quieres) y luego aceptas la respuesta (Aunque la hayas puesto tú puedes aceptarla pasadas unas horas si no me equivoco :))

Answer (score 0):

**Solución**

Como bien decía el compañero @Benito-B, para que spring cloud coja bien el directorio que queremos de Github, debemos poner en el servidor de configuración la URI raiz de nuestro repo de github, y crear una nueva línea donde le decimos al servidor que carpeta queremos que lea de nuestro repo de github. Siguiendo mi ejemplo quedaría de la siguiente forma el application.properties del servidor de configuración:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri= https://github.com/SeNTiHaDeS/config--repos
spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths=producto
```